# View music size by artist on iOS

Tags: ios, disk-space

I'm trying to free up space on an iPhone. Most of the space is used by music.

Is there a way to see which artists are using the most amount of space?

Logically this would be displayed under "System Settings app > General > Usage > Music", but unlike the "Usage > podcast" there is no break down beyond "All Music : x GB"

Can this be done easily in either iOS or iTunes, *on a per-device* basis (I only have a subset of music sync'd to the iPhone, so cannot just look at folder sizes in the "iTunes Music" directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can view all the music on your iPhone in iTunes, and can then sort by size of the each individual song. I don't think there's a way to sort by the size of the artist.

Note, you can only delete items from this list is you are using "manually manage music".

[image]